# How to solve the append value from counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, counter

I have one counter javascript:

```js
function animateSun() {
  var $elie = $("#sun");
  $({
    degree: 0
  }).animate({
    degree: 360
  }, {
    duration: 190999,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function(val) {
      now = Math.round(val);
      if ((now == 5) || (now == 10) || (now == 15)) //increament the value on every 5 value
      {
        var i = 0;
        $('#tam').text(i += 1);
      }
      $elie.css({
        transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
      });
      $('#demo').text('sec:' + now);
    },


  });
}
animateSun();
```

```css
#sun {
  position: absolute;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  animation: round 3s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="tam">0</p>
<p id="sun">sun</p>
```

The timer was running. At the time value reach `5` to add `1` on `#tam` then next reach to `10` `#tam` add with `1` change the value on 2. But its not working. Please help me. How increment the value of `#tam` on every 5 value change on `#demo`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to define the counter as global variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following. Apply `Math.floor()` to the `step/5`.

```js
function animateSun() {
  var $elie = $("#sun");
  $({
    degree: 0
  }).animate({
    degree: 360
  }, {
    duration: 190999,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function(val) {
      now = Math.round(val);
      $('#tam').text(Math.floor(val/5));
      $elie.css({
        transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
      });
      $('#demo').text('sec:' + now);
    },


  });
}
animateSun();
```

```css
#sun {
  position: absolute;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  animation: round 3s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="tam">0</p>
<p id="sun">sun</p>
```

Comment: So nice.Thanks @rejith

Answer (score 0):

As Rejith suggested, keep the counter value in a global variable. Currently, you are setting the counter to 0 everytime and then incrementing it, so it always results in 1.

```
var counter = 0;
function animateSun() {
  var $elie = $("#sun");
  $({
    degree: 0
  }).animate({
    degree: 360
  }, {
    duration: 190999,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function(val) {
      now = Math.round(val);
//          if ((now == 5) || (now == 10) || (now == 15)) //increment the value on every 5 value
      if( now % 5 == 0 )
      {
        $('#tam').text(counter++);
      }
      $elie.css({
        transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
      });
      $('#demo').text('sec:' + now);
    },


  });
}
animateSun();
```